# Chrome extension not working if convert in crx

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Today I create my first Chrome extension, if I use the code without transform in crx working without problem, if I convert in .crx after visiting the first website Chrome disables my plugin automatically, where is the problem ?

These are the files from my extension

```
mbp-di-admin:plugin admin$ ls
bgscript.js     contentscript.js    manifest.json
```

manifest.json :

```
{
    "background": {
    "scripts": ["bgscript.js"],
    "persisent": true
    },
    "name": "navigator.userAgent",
    "description": "My first plguin",
    "version": "1",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "web_accessible_resources": ["script.js", "settings.js", "bgscript.js"],
    "permissions": [ "webRequest", "webRequestBlocking", "<all_urls>" ],
    "content_scripts": [{
        "run_at": "document_start",
        "js": ["contentscript.js"],
    "all_frames": true,
        "matches": [
            "*://*/*"
        ]
    }]
}
```

Comment: Pay attention to the spelling. `persisent` should be `persistent`. Also it doesn't make sense to expose the background script in `web_accessible_resources`. Make sure you understand what you're doing, maybe start by reading the [extension overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview).

Comment: If you develop on Windows, where file system is case-insensitive, make sure the files are named EXACTLY as specified in manifest.json. That is not `ContentScript.js` but exactly `contentscript.js`.